# Is it possible that Jesus’ calming of the sea is a fulfillment of Psalm 107 28-31?

Tags: matthew, christology

Psalm 107:

> 28Then they cried out to the Lord in their trouble,
> and he brought them out of their distress.
> 29 **He stilled the storm to a whisper**;
> the waves of the sea were hushed.
> 30They were glad when it grew calm,
> and he guided them to their desired haven.
> 31Let them give thanks to the Lord for his unfailing love
> and his wonderful deeds for mankind.

Matthew 8:

> 23 Then he got into the boat and his disciples followed him. 24Suddenly a furious storm came up on the lake, so that the waves swept over the boat. But Jesus was sleeping. 25The disciples went and woke him, saying, “Lord, save us! We’re going to drown!”
>
> 26 He replied, “You of little faith, why are you so afraid?” Then he got up and rebuked the winds and the waves, and it was completely calm.
>
> 27The men were amazed and asked, “What kind of man is this? Even the winds and the waves obey him!”

Assuming they knew of that Psalm, is it possible that the disciples could have concluded that Jesus might be God?

Comment: Does Jesus claim to have caused the storm? (Zechariah 10:1) - Does Jesus claim to have calmed the waves? (Psalm 107:29) .. **Does this question only concern what Jesus' Disciples thought about Jesus - based the events in Matthew 8 (reflecting on their own thoughts, or scripture)?** : Please Clarify. - Good question, though.

Comment: Does this question only concern what Jesus' Disciples thought about the events in Matthew 8 (Based on their own thoughts, or scripture)? Both. Thanks for the comment. I added :)

Comment: You inspired me to raise the question of Joshua's divinity in [Joshua 10:12-13] when a man speaks to control nature.

Comment: Hi Tony, you might want to rework the title since it is impossible to say what the disciples knew about the Psalms or what they were thinking.

Comment: I did it. Thanks for the comment. Feel free to further edit my OP if you see a need :)

Comment: Great! I see the new edit. Thanks :) BTW, I have no formal training in hermeneutics :)

Comment: I appreciate your transparency, Tony! :)

Answer (score 3):

No. As late as Mt 16.17 the best Peter could come up with was:

Mt 16:16  And Simon Peter answered and said, Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God.

The others expressed no personal opinions.

Comment: +1 What about the others?

Comment: They did not speak up. they had no known thoughts on it.

Answer (score 2):

> Did it occur to the disciples that Jesus was God when he calmed the sea?
>
> <sup>Psalm 107:29</sup> **He stilled the storm** to a whisper; the waves of the sea were hushed.
>
> Did it occur to some of the disciples that Jesus was God?

Doubtful:

> <sup>Psalm 136:13</sup> **To him which divided the Red sea** into parts: for his mercy endures for ever.
>
> And made Israel to pass through the midst of it: for his mercy endures for ever.

The [Red Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_the_Red_Sea) was divided through Moses, the [Sea of Galilee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_of_Galilee) was stilled through Jesus Christ; in and of itself, this simply shows that God was working through both.